# AnimatePresence : Component exit transitions not working because i do not know what key to use

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Here is my code :

```js
<AnimatePresence initial={false}>
    {welcome && <Welcome></Welcome>}
    {instructions && <Instructions></Instructions>}
</AnimatePresence>
```

welcome is initially at true and instructions is initially at false. When i press a button those states reverse.

Both the Welcome and Instructions component have the following framer-motion properties set at the top most node :

```js
initial={{x: "100%"}} animate={{x:="0%"}} transition={{duration:2}} exit={{opacity:1}}
```

Right now the components dismount as soon as i switch component but i want the initial component to stay underneath while the new component slides on top of it.

I've tried putting as the key of those components :

- the corresponding state
- the corresponding relative path
- a corresponding string like "welcome" and "instructions"

I didn't really expect anything for the first 2 tries, and i expected the 3rd try to work but instead i got a weird result for every tries.

Instead of having the same result as without a key, instead the initial component didn't dismount until after 2 seconds but the new component didn't slide from right to left and instead appeared only after the 2 seconds went by.